# terraform 12 count date_template not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform0.12+, terraform-template-file

I'm upgrading to terraform 12 and have an asg module that references a root repository. As part of this, it uses a **data.template_file** resource to attach user data to the asg which is then put in to log files on the instances. The module looks as follows;

```
module "cef_fleet" {
       source  = "git::ssh://git@github.com/asg-repo.git?ref=terraform12"
       user_data_rendered                       = data.template_file.init.rendered
       instance_type                            = var.instance_type
       ami                                      = var.ami
       etc ...
```

which as you can see calls the data resource;

```
    data "template_file" "init" {
       count = signum(var.cluster_size_max)

       template = file("${path.module}/template-files/init.sh")

       vars = {
          account_name               = var.account_name
          aws_account_number         = var.aws_account_number
```

this works fine in terraform 11 but when I changed to terraoform 12 and try to apply I get this error:

```
*Because data.template_file.init has "count" set, its attributes must be
accessed on specific instances.
For example, to correlate with indices of a referring resource, use:
    data.template_file.init[count.index]*
```

if I change this in my module to **user_data_rendered = data.template_file.init[count.index]**
I then get this error;

```
    The "count" object can be used only in "resource" and "data" blocks, and only
    when the "count" argument is set.
```

I don't know what to do here. If I leave the .rendered in then it doesn't seem to recognise the [count.index] as I get the first error again. Has anyone any advice on what I need to do?

Comment: `user_data_rendered = data.template_file.init[0].rendered` doesn't use count and matches the old behavior. What you had in 0.11 technically worked, but you were always discarding all but the first template_file you were generating.

Comment: thank you @Jordanm that seems to be working. One thing though, this module "cef-fleet" is actually itself referenced by other modules. So we have two modules that reference this module, which then calls the root module. So would having this [0] somehow only allow the first high-level module to build the template?

Comment: It might be too late now if you've already been doing some manual upgrading work, but note that Terraform v0.12 has a command `terraform 0.12upgrade` which is intended to make a good first pass at the upgrade steps, including detecting and suggesting solutions for situations like these. There's more information on it in [the upgrade guide](https://www.terraform.io/upgrade-guides/0-12.html).